# How to get all SP Library IDs with PnPOnline useweblogin

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, pnp-powershell

Can you help my with this code?

```
#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite1"
 
Try {
    #Setup the context
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -useweblogin
     
    $webs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
    $web = $web[2]      #  (to select the first one)
    $lists = Get-PnPList
 
    #Get List Title and ID
    $Lists | Select Title, ID
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the below PnP PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose

#Site Variable; replace with actual site url
$SiteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/"

#Connect to PnP Online 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin 

#Another way to connect
#$cred= Get-Credential
#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred

#Process the root web First
$rootWeb= Get-PnPWeb

$allLists=@()

#all list/library from the root
$allLists=Get-PnPList -Web $rootWeb

Write-host "Number of lists in the root web: " $allLists.Count

#get all sub sites
$subWebs =Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

foreach($subweb in $subWebs)
{
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $subweb.Url -UseWebLogin 
   #Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred

   $lists = Get-PnPList -Web $subweb
   $allLists+=$lists
}

Write-host "Number of list in all Webs: " $allLists.Count

 #Get List Title and ID
 $allLists | Select Title, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to mention about the script. `Get-PnPList` returns all the lists and libraries. If you want to return only document libraries, please use
`$DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}`